# How many coins does the Phantom Stranger have left?

Tags: dc

The origins of the Phantom Stanger are as follows:

He is Judas Iscariot who was paid 30 pieces of silver to betray Jesus, leading to Jesus' crucifixion and subsequent resurrection. As punishment, the Phantom Stranger was forced to wander the earth and do acts of penance.  He was also punished by wearing a necklace made of the 30 pieces of silver used in his betrayal of Jesus.

However, after certain acts, the Phantom Stranger loses one of his coins.

The creation of Spectre:
[("A Stranger Among Us" Phantom Stranger v4, #0 (November 2012))](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/The_Phantom_Stranger_Vol_4_0)

[Bringing Raven to Trigon](https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-c17828cd266f80f9800a188e14b23a9a-lq)

As stated in the sources above, the Phantom Stranger will achieve "redemption" when the last coin is gone.

Given these examples (as well as any others), how many coins does the Phantom Stranger have left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the 2014 "[Five Years From Now](https://www.weirdsciencedccomics.com/2014/09/phantom-stranger-futures-end-1-review.html)" story in *Phantom Stranger: Futures End #1*, the Phantom Stranger uses his last piece of silver to pay the ferryman.

> Our story begins with what could be the last day of The Stranger's suffering.  On a lonely pier, The Stranger waits for a ferry to take him to the new Council of Eternity, that will judge his fate.  The ferryman arrives and asks for a payment and it's so cool to see that The Stranger pays with his last silver coin burdening his soul and when he hands it over, the mantle of The Stranger fades away and just leaves the man that he was two thousand years earlier.  Instantly a gateway appears to The Stranger's side and it's time to meet the new Council and await their judgement.

However

> In the end we find out that the Ferryman is actually the wife that Phantom Stranger had when he took over the life of Philip Stark and that she's been waiting for him since she died and that they've walked beside one another for countless lives.  She tells him that even though she wants him to be with her, the world needs The Phantom Stranger more and hands him back his last piece of silver.  As the ferry vanishes The Phantom Stranger rises with new resolve now that he can be The Stranger with all the weight of his sins released.